# Azure nodejs sdk: long polling for queue message listener

Tags: node.js, azure, queue

Is it possible to create a message listener to receive messages from a service bus queue (not storage queue) only when messages are available?

Actually my implementation consists in a setInterval function calling receive operation:

```
var service = azure.createServiceBusService( azureEnpoint );    

var repeat = function() {
                    service.receiveQueueMessage(me.name, function (error, receivedMessage) {
                        if (!error) {
                            logger.debug(receivedMessage, "Received message from queue "+ me.name);
                            callback(error, receivedMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }


                setInterval(repeat, me.pollingInterval);
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, Azure Service Bus Queues / Topic Subscriptions are pull-only.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of, you use long polling whereby you check for a message and wait for a long time for a response. The good side of this is you only get charged for a single request. Replace seconds with how long you want to wait for a response. The maximum is 24 days.

```
service.receiveQueueMessage(me.name, { timeoutIntervalInS: seconds },  
                                    function (error, receivedMessage)
```

There's a full example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802604.aspx

Comment: Actually, it seems the [maximum timoutoutIntervalInS for REST-based clients is 55 seconds](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/).

Comment: Again, sort of. I can't remember offhand which it was but one of the clients I looked at would keep the connection open by sending periodic pings.